# How to prevent a particular string from being printed in find_all()?

Tags: python, web-scraping

How to exclude a substring from being printed in object `obj`

```
obj = soup.find_all('tag')
if "string" not in obj.text:
    print obj.text
```

But due to the use of find_all() method for object obj nothing is being printed.
What should be done so that we print only the wanted string in obj.

Comment: Can you post a complete, executable example?

Comment: *But due to the use of find_all() method for object obj nothing is being printed*, yes there is definitely some output, it would be an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the list returned by `find_all()`:

```
for i in soup.find_all('tag'):
    txt = i.text
    if 'string' not in txt:
        print txt
```

Alternatively, you could create another list where the unwanted tags are filtered out:

```
filtered_lst = [i for i in soup.find_all('tag') if 'string' not in i.text]
```

This will give you a list of `Tag` objects similar to that returned by `find_all()`, but with only the tags that do not include `'string'` in their `.text`. After that you can do what you want it it:

```
for tag in filtered_lst:
    print tag.text
```

## Update:

On the other hand, if your goal is to simply filter `'string'` from the text of the tag, you can use the `replace()` method of strings:

```
for tag in soup.find_all('tag'):
    print tag.text.replace('string', '')
```

However, keep in mind that this will remove `'string'` wherever it is in the text, and may leave unwanted whitespace to be removed later. For example:

```
>>> 'hellostring string'.replace('string', '')
'hello '
```

Comment: I did that too but still it's the same.All the strings contained in that list is not printed

Comment: Make sure your variable names match. I see you using `obj` and `Obj`. Python is very case sensitive.

Comment: That's actually a typo but the actual code is clean.

Comment: Also, there was a typo in my code too. I had the line `txt = i.txt` which should be `txt = i.text`. If neither of my suggestions work, can you please post more of your code. I was not able to reproduce your problem. Also, ensure that `'string'` is not actually in the tag text. Before the `if` line you could add `print txt` to see what you are actually testing in your `if` statement.

Comment: Sure will try and be back with the results.Though the concern ,that I have is that it seems as though all the strings acquired from the tag using find_all() is stored in one index of the list.Is my instinct right?

Comment: I am not sure if I follow what you mean, but when you do `find_all()` you will get a list of `Tag` objects. Each of these objects has a `.text` attribute which will give you the text of that particular tag. In the loop in my example, I am reassigning the `txt` variable to the the `.text` of a new `Tag` at each iteration. In other words, I think you intuition in this particular case is not correct. The best way to reason about these things is to open an interactive Python interpreter and experiment. Get your list of tags, inspect the elements, see what properties they have, etc.

Comment: The problem is that 'string' is in tag text and I want to prevent it from being printed while I print others In the same tag text

Comment: AH! I have misunderstood this whole time! So you always want to print the text of the tag, but just filter `'string'` from the text printed? I will update my answer if that is the case.

Comment: Yup.Thanks for the effort.